# Big CSS Sprite Image (Works as slow in low cpu computers)

Tags: css, xhtml, sprite, css-sprites

My site have a big css sprite image.

Site: http://www.protohaber.com/demo

Sprite Image: http://www.protohaber.com/demo/templates/v1/images/proto_sprite.png

My site is works slow (e.g. page scrolling slow, etc..) at browser in some computers (low cpu computers)

Comment: I'd suggest possibly chopping the sprite up into 2 or three sprites. Possibly consider whether or not having all of those images in a sprite is really needed at all.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Thanks, im chopping sprite image.

Comment: man you should upvote some answer :S

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use [PNG Gauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/) to optimize the image.

Another Solution could be to split the Sprite into two or even more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the principal reason for this is because the image is too big (almost 1.5 Megabytes), So just imagine how much the cpu have to calculate to move the background from one side to another. I think you sprite has a lot of resources which doesn't belong to it (like some images (the girl, caution alert, etc). Also you are mixing a lot of color at the same sprite which make the images bigger because has more colors to render.

I think one option is break apart the sprite into separate one which will make the file smaller `(the slow processors can handle, render and move better small images)`, remove the images like (the girl, caution alert, etc) and make them jpg file which will make the file also smaller.

the idea of sprites is reduce the request to the server but if this reduce the performance of you application is best idea to make a couple of more request and have a better performance for the final user.